# Updating NSDate and NSString in background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring

Good day! I just want to ask if how can i update this codes in background?

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd  hh:mm:ss"];
self.txtTimestamp.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSString *buyUrl = @"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AkgWFqjLQz0TdHdMQzBsc1lhaGFPZEFCYXBLWEt1Q0E&single=true&gid=3&output=txt";
NSString *buyFile= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:buyUrl] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
self.txtBuydata.text = buyFile;
```

the date and time is updating IF the app is freshly opened because it is in ViewDidLoad and also the NSString code. Now, How can i update the NSDate and NSString on background every minute? so even the app is in background the NSSting is updating every minute even the app is in background or open. thanks a lot!

Comment: can you explain why do you want to change the link? so that community can guide you in right direction and its not possible to update every minute this url from background

Comment: i dont want to change the link. that link is from a google spreadsheet. so what i want to do is update the referenced textfield in the NSString so it will show in the UITextField.. ok so it cannot update in background? it is updating if the app is freshly opened. but if you minimize it and open it again it is not changing. i also tried to put the code in ViewWillAppear but it's not changing.

Comment: Yes bacause when you press the home button and come back your viewController will not call the viewWillAppear delegate

Comment: Yes, because when you press home button and again open the app your viewWillAppear delegate not called, you have to use notification for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `NSTimer` to do an action repeatedly.

### Example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //...
    //declare "NSTimer *timerTest;" in the .h
    timerTest = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(doThisRepeatedly:)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];
    //...
}

- (void)doThisRepeatedly:(NSTimer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@",sender);
    //...
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd  hh:mm:ss"];
    self.txtTimestamp.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    //...

    //fyi: if you want to stop the timer from within this method (generally in a condition)
    //then use the following commented line:
    //[sender invalidate];
}
```

To stop the timer from within another method then reference it by it's object name and simply:

```
[timerTest invalidate];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement Local notification for knowing that your application is become active so that you can update your tag like

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(updateFieldMethod:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```